# Fastest way to explore the grid and find a flag

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, graph-algorithm

I have an n x n grid with obstacles in the form of blocks. I would need to find a flag somewhere in this grid by starting at a random point. You can turn left, right or move 
forward/backward.

At each point in the grid you have information about the four blocks (up, down, left, right) of you. BFS seems like a good solution. But it made me wonder if there was a faster or better exploration algorithm?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say "fastest" do you mean finding the fastest way to the flag or algorithm that finds the path quickest?

Comment: I meant fastest way to the flag. (number of cells traversed)

Comment: Since you have information about the four surrounding blocks at each time, and nothing more, I'd say use DFS.

Answer (score 0):

BFS is indeed the algorithm you need. As additional benefit you will find the shortest path in terms of cells crossed to the flag. Also please note you need not store the whole graph in any "conventional way" the grid is good enough representation of a graph itself in this case. Many of my students fail to understand that.

Comment: What would you suggest if at each point, I have information about the four surrounding blocks (up, down, left, right).

Answer (score 0):

This seems a normal exploration problem on a grid. If you use BFS then you find all points with distance <= distance between start and flag.

However, I would recommend to use some optimizations.

You could use A* if you know the coordinates of the flag (which is unclear from your question).

If you don't have the flag coordinates, you could try to exploit the information you have from your blocks. On a square grid, BFS creates circular search fronts meaning that you obtain all information on the points within a circular shaped area around your start. This means that you will evaluate all points in that region. You could try to maximize your exploration by prioritizing the evaluation of points that give you more information on your graph = points that have many unknown neighbors.

This will redirect your search to evaluate new points as soon as possible. Once you find the flag, you have an upper bound on the distance and you can explore the unknown parts of the graph that might improve the bound. You could also take into account the distance from the start in your priority function to avoid your search going too far. The balance in the priority function will depend on your grid and the amount of obstacles.